# Suppose that $f''(a) = 0$. Prove that $f'''(a) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Suppose that $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is three (or more) times
>   differentiable at the point $a$ and that $f(x) ≤ f(a)$ for all $x ∈
> \Bbb R$. Suppose that $f''(a) = 0$. Prove that $f'''(a) = 0$.

I don't understand this question. Just because we have a maximum for this function and second derivative equals to $0$ doesn't mean the third derivative should also be zero. We have insuffucient information to conclude that right? what am I missing here?

Comment: Write the Taylor expansion of order $3$ and you will see it. Use that $f'(a)=0$ and that $f''(a)=0$. If you had the $(x-a)^3$ term, which is negative at one side of $a$ and positive at the other, could you have maximum at $a$?

Comment: @user647486 Very nice! However, you also have to take the error term into account.

Comment: A heuristic argument: there is a max at $a$. So $f'$ is decreasing in a neighborhood of $a$ and $f'(a) = 0$. Now consider $f''$. It is negative right and left from $a$ but zero at $a$. So it has a minimum there. Hence $f'''(a) = 0$.

Comment: Alternatively, assume $f'''(a) \ne 0$. Without loss of generalization, you can assume $f'''(a) > 0$, which leads to a contradiction as you move up to $f(a)$.

Comment: so the taylor series is $P_{3, a} = f(a) + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3$ and using a theorem i get $lim_{x \to a}f(x) - (\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + f(a)) = 0$ where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ is a local maximum for $f$, we have $f'(a) =0$. Now consider on the contrary that $f''' (a) >0$. Since $f''(a) =0$ it follows that $a$ is a local strict minimum for $f' $. And hence there is a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $f'(x) >f'(a) =0$ for all $x\in I, x\neq a$. Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing in $I$ and $a$ can not be a local maximum of $f$. This contradiction shows that $f''' (a) $ can't be positive. A similar argument shows that $f''' (a) $ can't be negative and is thus zero.